# React Native: Access this.props Inside Function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I managed to fetch data and show to UI with this code:

```
export default class BoxGarage extends Component {
    render() {
        let garage = this.props.garage;
        garage.name = garage.name.replace('strtoreplace', 'My Garage');

        let cars = garage.cars.length ?
            garage.cars.map((val, key) => {
                return (
                    <Car key={key} car={val} />
                )
            }) : (
                <View style={styles.boxEmpty}>
                    <Text style={styles.textEmpty}>(No Cars)</Text>
                </View>
            );

        return (
            <View style={styles.boxGarage}>
                <Text>{ garage.name }</Text>
                { cars }
            </View>
        )
    }       
}
```

Then I tried to change with a function, but no cars shown. What is missing?

```
export default class BoxGarage extends Component {
    render() {
        let garage = this.props.garage;
        garage.name = garage.name.replace('strtoreplace', 'My Garage');

        cars = function(garage) {
            if (garage.cars.length) {
                garage.cars.map((val, key) => {
                    return (
                        <Car key={key} car={val} />
                    );
                });
            }
            else {
                return (
                    <View style={styles.boxEmpty}>
                        <Text style={styles.textEmpty}>(No Cars)</Text>
                    </View>
                );
            }
        }

        return (
            <View style={styles.boxGarage}>
                <Text>{ garage.name }</Text>
                { cars(this.props.garage) }
            </View>
        )
    }       
}
```

And I think I should refactor for best practice either using constructor or just move the function outside render, but I don't know what it is. Please advice.

Comment: your `if` case doesn't have a return statement, so it's implicitly returning undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your second code doesn't work is that you're not returning anything from your function if garage.cars.length > 0.

```
if (garage.cars.length) {
  // Added a return statement on the next line
  return garage.cars.map((val, key) => {
    return (
      <Car key={key} car={val} />
    );
  });
}
```

That said, i think your first version of the code was much cleaner. If a piece of code got complicated enough that i was tempted to make an inline function to do calculations, i'd either pull that out to another class method, or to another component. In your case though, just doing a ternary or an if/else will be much better.